# No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, concurrency

I've the following class:

```
@Component
public class DasServiceHelper {

    @Autowired ConcurrentTaskExecutor executor;


    protected void retrieveDASReferenceData() {

        Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>> callable1 = new Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>>() {
            @Override public List<ReferenceDataType> call() throws Exception {
                //Some method logic
            }
        };

        Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>> callable2 = new Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>>() {
            @Override public List<ReferenceDataType> call() throws Exception {
                //Some method logic
            }
        };

        Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>> callable3 = new Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>>() {
            @Override public List<ReferenceDataType> call() throws Exception {
                //Some method logic
            }
        };

        Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>> callable4 = new Callable<List<ReferenceDataType>>() {
            @Override public List<ReferenceDataType> call() throws Exception {
                //Some method logic
            }
        };

        Future<List<ReferenceDataType>> result1 = executor.submit(callable1);
        Future<List<ReferenceDataType>> result2 = executor.submit(callable2);
        Future<List<ReferenceDataType>> result3 = executor.submit(callable3);
        Future<List<ReferenceDataType>> result4 = executor.submit(callable4);
        Future<List<ReferenceDataType>> result5 = executor.submit(callable5);
    }
```

This is my spring configuration xml:

```
<bean name="dasServiceHelper" class="com.nyl.corp.das.DasServiceHelper"/>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor"/>
```

I'm invoking the `retrieveDASReferenceData()` from my service class.

When I compile the code, I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
```

Any idea what I'm missing here.

EDIT:
Spring configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nyl.corp">
        <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.nyl.corp.*.web.*.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="beanNameResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
        <property name = "order" value = "0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="excelView" class="com.nyl.corp.das.web.ExcelView" />
    <bean id="reportExcelView" class="com.nyl.corp.das.web.ReportExcelView" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <cache:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
        p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache" />

    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
        p:config-location="classpath:dasEhCache.xml" p:shared="true"/>

    <bean name="dasServiceHelper" class="com.nyl.corp.das.DasServiceHelper"/>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor"/>
<!--      <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="10-20" queue-capacity="11"/>
     <bean id="asyncBean" class="com.nyl.corp.das.DasServiceHelper"/> -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Can you post everything in your spring configuration xml

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBond I've updated my question with spring config file.

Comment: Remove either the bean declaration or the `@Component` annotation for `DasServiceHelper`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I tried that..but the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Check how many version of spring jars included on your classpath. Sometime you accidentally included multiple version and this happen